# What is best for performance batch inserts or sliced multiple batch inserts?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I noticed that when i use db->insert_batch function Codeigniter slices rows per 100 inserts.

What is the reason behind that ? Isn't it more gainful to do all at once ?

Also from that perspective with Codeigniter, as far as i know, it's not possible to do multiple inserts to multiple tables in one connection.

What can be the performance comparison between those three scenarios ?

1- Do 2220 Inserts in one connection. 20 to one table, 200 to other, 2200 to last table.

2- Same inserts, as CodeIgniter ActiveRecord library suggests (?) 10 to one table in once query, 200 to second table in 2 different queries, 2000 inserts to third table in 20 queries.

3- 2220 different queries for each row.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can only insert to one table at a time so #1 vs. #3 doesn't make sense to me (and your numbers don't add up)

The reason to batch inserts is because they cause the highly restrictive write locks. Depending on the DB engine, inserts can cause table-level write locks, building up the request queue and eventually denying requests when the pool reaches its limit

The batching allows for inserts to be done and occassionally release locks allowing presumably faster queries to get their time in before locking again.

Answer (score 0):

If you can wrap everything in a transaction, it would boost performance. Look into delayed inserts as well.